# How can I orderby id when I use distinct on Web2py

Tags: postgresql, web2py

I'm using postgresql database and have a `log` table. I want to show the ticket information from this `log` table and want to sort by id. But ticket id has duplicate data, so I use distinct to filter, and then I can't sort by id when I use distinct.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

```
rows = db(db.log.ticket_id != '').select(db.log.ALL, orderby=~db.log.id, distinct=db.log.ticket_id , limitby=((page-1) * PAGE_ROWS, (page*PAGE_ROWS)))
```

I got the error message:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

And I try to:

```
rows = db(db.log.ticket_id != '').select(db.log.ALL, orderby=~db.log.id|db.log.ticket_id, distinct=db.log.ticket_id , limitby=((page-1) * PAGE_ROWS, (page*PAGE_ROWS)))
```

But still can't work...

Comment: *SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match **initial** ORDER BY expressions*. The error message is pretty straightforward, try `orderby=~db.log.ticket_id|db.log.id`. This is known limitation of `DISTINCT ON` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: So, if I want sort by `id` is impossible?

Comment: You cannot sort by `id` first, without specifying it in the `DISCTINT ON` clause too (this may be enough in some cases, but you should provide more information from your table structure in order to anwser this) -- another workaround is that you can use a sub-select & order your results in the outer select.